# AWS boto3 InvalidAccessKeyId when using IAM role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-iam

I upload to and download from S3 with a presigned post/url. The presigned url/post are generated with boto3 in the Lambda function (it is deployed with zappa).

While I add my `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` and `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` as env variable works perfectly. Then I removed my credentials and I add an IAM role to lambda to full access to S3 bucket. After that the lambda return with the presigned URL and `getObject` is working well, however when i want to upload object through the URL, it returns an `InvalidAccessKeyId` error. The used key id `ASIA...` which means those are temporary credentials.

It seems that the lambda does not use IAM role, or what is the problem?

```py
class S3Api:

    def __init__(self):
            self.s3 = boto3.client(
                's3',
                region_name='eu-central-1'
            )

    def generate_store_url(self, key):
        return self.s3.generate_presigned_post(FILE_BUCKET,
                                               key,
                                               Fields=None,
                                               Conditions=None,
                                               ExpiresIn=604800)

    def generate_get_url(self, key):
        return self.s3.generate_presigned_url('get_object',
                                              Params={'Bucket': FILE_BUCKET,
                                                      'Key': key},
                                              ExpiresIn=604800)
```

My result for `sts:getCallerIdentity`:

```json
{
     'UserId': '...:dermus-api-dev',
     'Account': '....',
     'Arn': 'arn:aws:sts::....:assumed-role/dermus-api-dev-ZappaLambdaExecutionRole/dermus-api-dev',
    'ResponseMetadata': {
        'RequestId': 'a1bd7c31-0199-472e-bff7-b93a4f855450',
        'HTTPStatusCode': 200,
        'HTTPHeaders': {
            'x-amzn-requestid': 'a1bd7c31-0199-472e-bff7-b93a4f855450',
            'content-type': 'text/xml',
            'content-length': '474',
            'date': 'Tue, 09 Mar 2021 08:36:30 GMT'
        },
        'RetryAttempts': 0
    }
}
```

dermus-api-dev-ZappaLambdaExecutionRole role is attached to dermus-api-dev lambda.

Comment: You can use `sts:getCallerIdentity` to figure out which credentials it's currently using to talk to AWS services. [Here are the python docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sts.html#STS.Client.get_caller_identity) for that. Please edit your question to include it's output from Lambda but obfuscate the account id (12-digit number in the Account and ARN result).

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question with the result.

Comment: That means it's definitely using the correct credentials, so they're most likely expired, see my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Presigned URLs and the Lambda credentials work in a non-obvious way together.

From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), emphasis mine:

> - Anyone with valid security credentials can create a presigned URL. However, in order to successfully access an object, the presigned URL must be created by someone who has permission to perform the operation that the presigned URL is based upon.
> - The credentials that you can use to create a presigned URL include:
>
>   - IAM instance profile: Valid up to 6 hours
>   - AWS Security Token Service : Valid up to 36 hours when signed with permanent credentials, such as the credentials of the AWS account root user or an IAM user
>   - IAM user: Valid up to 7 days when using AWS Signature Version 4
> - To create a presigned URL that's valid for up to 7 days, first designate IAM user credentials (the access key and secret access key) to the SDK that you're using. Then, generate a presigned URL using AWS Signature Version 4.
> - **If you created a presigned URL using a temporary token, then the URL expires when the token expires, even if the URL was created with a later expiration time.**

Bottom line: The URL might be expired if you wait too long, because the Lambda functions credentials are already expired.

Comment: OK, thanks. So how can I solve this problem? Should I always assume role each time Lambda is invoked?

Comment: The second to  last bullet points should help - if you need long-lived presigned-URLs you should create a technical IAM user and store its keys in e.g. the Secrets Manager. In Lambda you retrieve the keys, use them to create the presigned URL and send that back to your client.

Comment: Ok, thanks.But I use uploading ASAP, I do not really understand why it is expired. And getObject why works, when putObject not.

Comment: This was exactly the answer I was needing - it sent me down a path to use STS to assumeRole of a different IAM role within the lambda function, where that other IAM role had the necessary S3 permissions.  I use that assumed role's credentials for S3 instead of the Lambda execution role.  This documentation loosely helped: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-function-assume-iam-role/